# meta-analysis multiple outcome variables

Tags: r, correlation

As you might be able to tell from the sample of my dataset, it contains a lot of dependency, with each study providing multiple outcomes for the construct I am looking at. I was planning on using the **metacor** library because I only have information about the sample size but not variance. However, all methods I came across to that deal with dependency such as the package **rubometa** use variance (I know some people average the effect size for the study but I read that tends to produce larger error rates). Do you know if there is an equivalent package that uses only sample size or is it mathematically impossible to determine the weights without it?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please note that I am a student, no expert.

You could use the ***escalc*** function of the *metafor* package to calculate variances for each effect size. In the case of correlations, it only needs the raw correlation coefficients and the corresponding sample sizes.
See section "Outcome Measures for Variable Association" @ https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/metafor/versions/2.1-0/topics/escalc